Why is the force applied at end of rod by the axis of rotation $R$, at time, $t=0$, equal to $R=\sqrt{(( M\cdot g)^2+( \frac{1}{2} \cdot F)^2)}$?
the question is regarding a problem in Rotational Motion for rigid bodies in AP Physics 1. I have tried to translate it as best as I could from Swedish. The problem is as follows:

"A homogeneous rod with length $L$ and mass $M$ is fixed to the horizontal axis. The rod can freely move around its axis. Initially, the rod is standing vertically. At t=0, a force F is applied at the end of the Rod (see image)
What is the magnitude of the Reaction Force, R, that the axis of rotation applies to the rod at t=0?"


I have tried to draw a Free-Body Diagram with the "Reaction Force" split into its x- and y-components. My teacher has published the solution, which is $R=\sqrt{(( M\cdot g)^2+( \frac{1}{2}  \cdot F)^2)}$ with no explanation... I understand that we are finding the hypothenuse R via Pythagoras but it is especially the fact that the solution implies that $Rx = \frac{1}{2} \cdot F$. I cant seem to wrap my head around as to why though? And how do we know so?

Is the rod fixed to the horizontal plane instead of axis mentioned in the question? What this means is that gravity is not important here, correct?

You need to consider $R_x$, that the reaction force along the x-axis, is applied on the pivot.

and then look at the equations of motion along the x axis and the rotational sense
$$\begin{aligned}
  F - R_x & = M \ddot{x} \\
  \tfrac{L}{2} F + \tfrac{L}{2} R_x & = I \ddot{\phi} 
\end{aligned}$$
where $I = \tfrac{1}{12} M L^2$ is the mass moment of inertia of the rod about the center of mass.
In addition, consider the kinematics where $\ddot{x} = \tfrac{L}{2} \ddot{\phi}$ when starting for a resting position.
The equations above are solved for the two unknowns, $\alpha$ the rotational acceleration, and $R$ the requested reaction force.
$$ \begin{aligned}
  \ddot{\phi} & = \frac{2 F \tfrac{L}{2}}{I +M \left( \tfrac{L}{2} \right)^2} \\
  R_x & = \left( \frac{I - M \left( \tfrac{L}{2} \right)^2}{I+M \left( \tfrac{L}{2} \right)^2} \right) F
\end{aligned}$$
Using the MMOI for a rod the above is
$$ \begin{aligned}
  \ddot{\phi} & = \frac{3 F} { M L} \\
  R_x & = -\tfrac{1}{2} F \\ 
\end{aligned}$$
The direction of $R_x$ is not in the way I drew in the diagram thus.
In total, the force on the pivot is the vector sum of the side reaction and the weight
$$ R = \sqrt{ \left( M g \right)^2 + \left( \mbox{-}\tfrac{1}{2} F \right)^2 } $$

If you investigate the value and direction of $R_x$ in relation to where the force $F$ is applied, then you will discover where the axis of percussion is.
Call $b$ the distance from the center of mass where the force $F$ is applied and solve as above to get
$$ \begin{aligned}
  R_x & = \left( \frac{\tfrac{L}{2}-3b}{2L} \right) F \\
  \ddot{\phi}  & = \frac{3 F \left(b+\tfrac{L}{2}\right) }{4 M \left( \tfrac{L}{2} \right)}
\end{aligned}$$
This means that the reaction force has the following cases
$$ \begin{cases} 
  R_x < 0 & b > \tfrac{1}{6} L \\
  R_x = 0 & b = \tfrac{1}{6} L \\
  R_x > 0 & b < \tfrac{1}{6} L \\
\end{cases} $$
The middle case where the force $F$ is applied at $1/6$ the length of the rod from the center of mass is the axis of percussion where the rotation is induced with no reaction force.

I see, I assume that the reaction force on my Free Body Diagram was drawn at the incorrect place then. My follow-up question is then, is there always a reaction force R - in the opposite direction of the external force F applied on the rod - at the pivot?

The kinematic equation $~x=\tan \left( \phi \right) \cdot \dfrac{L}{2}$

@Eli - and its derivatives $\dot{x} = \tfrac{L}{2} \dot{\phi}$ when $\phi=0$ leads the acceleration $$a = \ddot{x} = \tfrac{L}{2} \ddot{\phi}$$

@Niko - not always in the opposite direction. It depends on the point of application of the force $F$. If you  look at the equation for $R_x$ you can find the conditions when $R_x=0$ when by varying the $L/2$ in front of $F$ in the equations of motion.

@JohnAlexiou if you take $~x=\tan(\phi)~\frac L2~$
solving the 3 equations and for $~\phi=0~$ you obtain $~Rx=\frac F2~$ this is the correct solution

the 3 equations are
$$~ m,\ddot x=F+R_x~$$
$$~\frac{m,L^2}{12},\alpha=\frac L2,(F-R_x)~$$
$$~2,{\frac {{\dot\phi}^{2}\sin \left( \phi \right) }{ \left( \cos
\left( \phi \right)  \right) ^{3}}}-2,{\frac {{\ddot x}}{L}}+{\frac
{\alpha}{ \left( \cos \left( \phi \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
=0$$

@Eli - I have confirmed your result. I must have gone wrong somewhere. I will investigate.

@Niko - I did some corrections prompted by Eli, and it turns out the reaction force is to the right since the value is negative to the way I drew the diagram.

The solution your teacher has given $R=\sqrt{(( M\cdot g)^2+( \frac{1}{2}  \cdot F)^2)}$ is equivalent to the resultant force initially acting on the top of the rod. This has components $R_y = Mg$ and $R_x = F$ and the combined resultant force is given by Pythagoras as you mentioned. This resultant force acting on the top of the rod is equivalent to the reaction force exerted by the pivot on the bottom of the rod.
